# Warning: include(Abraham\TwitterOAuth\Config.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Varien\Autoload.php on line 94

Tags: magento-1.9

Can somebody help me, pardon me i'm new to magento.. i want to use https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth as external lib i put it in magento 1.9 lib directory

the folder tree like:`lib\TwitterOAuth\src`

then i use it in a .phtml page and its controller in \design\frontend\base\default\template

then i include the class:

```
require Mage::getBaseDir('lib') . '/TwitterOauth/autoload.php';
use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;
```

Like 2 weeks ago it was running smoothly i could use the class until the user logged in and calledback, and i didn't face error like this. i don't how now its throwing error. why varien autoload take part on this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my own fault actually to have it set in Developer Mode by commenting the conditional if in index.php.

```
//if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
    Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
//}
```

I was testing something, the fix is just by uncommenting it back. I guess have to becareful on this one. lol